# How to show a custom table field on prodct page in prestashop

Tags: php, html, mysql, prestashop

I create a table named `ps_product_kg` with four fields:

`id` , `id_product`, `product_kg`, `product_moq`

I need to show `product_kg` and `product_moq` on product page and also in cart summary.

I want to know where i need to call table fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom module for that, Or you can override the product Class and add your table fields to the product object, than you can access these field from your tpl.

Answer (score 0):

Your can use product page hooks and cart hooks like: displayLeftColumnProduct, displayFooterProduct, displayProductButtons, displayProductTab - displayProductTabContent, displayRightColumnProduct, displayShoppingCart, displayShoppingCartFooter.

You can find more info about hooks and how to used here: [Hooks in Prestashop 1.5](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5) It work for 1.6 version too.

Good luck.